# Using CLR 4.0 Background GC on a Server

Tags: garbage-collection, clr, windows-server-2008

We're building a MMO server, highly optimized for latency. 
So, with the CLR 4.0 and with introduced new workstation GC, is it now possible to use Background Garbage collection on a Windows Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently not. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/archive/2008/11/19/so-what-s-new-in-the-clr-4-0-gc.aspx) article, which specifically states that Microsoft is *not offering background GC for server GC in V4.0* (though it looks like this is *under consideration*).

Answer (score 2):

You might also find [this essay (PDF)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/9/C/99CA11E6-774E-41C1-88B5-09391A70AF02/RapidAdditionWhitePaper.pdf) interesting, given what you're trying to do.